# Commands not working in a script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to write my first bash script to automate some boring stuff I have to type everytime but can't get it working.
I've created pgAdmin.sh in my home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/enviromentpy/pgadmin4
source bin/activate
python lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py
```

When I run it using ./pgAdmin.sh I get:

```
./pgAdmin.sh: line 2: cd: /opt/enviromentpy/pgadmin4: No such file or 
directory
./pgAdmin.sh: line 3: bin/activate: No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But when I open terminal and just put those commands one by one from Home directory it works just fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you got your paths wrong.

Comment: maybe the path is `/opt/enviromentpy/pgAdmin4`

Comment: Yeah, brain fart ;) Add as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a simple spelling mistake.

Instead of `enviromentpy` you probably meant to write `enviromentpy` (notice the extra `n`)